# How to deal with multiple duplicate keys (Fn::Sub) in a aws cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a policy that is being made in a cloudformation template. I want to add two resources to the policy, they end up being `arn::bucket` and `arn::bucket/*`. The issue is that the `arn` is a parameter and I get the error: `[cfn-lint] E0000: Duplicate resource found "Fn::Sub" (line 161)`. I understand that it doesn't like the duplicates.

```
"RolePolicies": {
          "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
          "Properties": {
              "PolicyName": "GetGEBucketPutCustomerBucket",
              "PolicyDocument": {
                  "Statement": [
                      {
                          "Action": [
                            "s3:PutObject",
                            "s3:GetObject",
                            "s3:GetObjectAttributes",
                            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                            "s3:ListBucket",
                            "s3:DeleteObject"
                          ],
                          "Effect": "Allow",
                          "Resource": {
                              "Fn::Sub": [
                                  "${arn}/*",
                                  {
                                      "arn": {
                                          "Ref": "CustomerS3BucketARN"
                                      }
                                  }
                              ],
                              "Fn::Sub": [
                                "${arn}",
                                {
                                    "arn": {
                                        "Ref": "CustomerS3BucketARN"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              },
              "Roles": [
                  {
                      "Ref": "InstanceRole"
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "a713fcc6-95c8-423f-a5b8-0020a81e5ce4"
              }
          }
      }
```

However, this cloudformation is allowed to run, but produces errors. When viewing the policy in IAM console window after create, I see that both of the resources were not created.
[image: IAM Console JSON]

IAM policy editor gives me this error.
`Ln 1, Col 0Missing Version: We recommend that you specify the Version element to help you with debugging permission issues.` since the resource than ends with `/*` wasn't created by cloud formation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to fix this was split up the actions into multiple parts. This allowed me to use the `Fn::Sub` function and keep things separated. The only downside is that I had to create 4 policy statements instead of 2.

```
"RolePolicies": {
          "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
          "Properties": {
              "PolicyName": "GetGEBucketPutCustomerBucket",
              "PolicyDocument": {
                  "Statement": [
                      {
                          "Action": [
                            "s3:ListBucket"
                          ],
                          "Effect": "Allow",
                          "Resource": {
                              "Fn::Sub": [
                                  "${arn}",
                                  {
                                      "arn": {
                                          "Ref": "GeS3BucketARN"
                                      }
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      },
                      {
                        "Action": [
                          "s3:GetObject",
                          "s3:GetObjectAttributes",
                          "s3:GetObjectTagging"
                        ],
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Resource": {
                            "Fn::Sub": [
                                "${arn}/*",
                                {
                                    "arn": {
                                        "Ref": "GeS3BucketARN"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Action": [
                          "s3:ListBucket"
                        ],
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Resource": {
                            "Fn::Sub": [
                                "${arn}",
                                {
                                    "arn": {
                                        "Ref": "CustomerS3BucketARN"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                      {
                          "Action": [
                            "s3:PutObject",
                            "s3:GetObject",
                            "s3:GetObjectAttributes",
                            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                            "s3:DeleteObject"
                          ],
                          "Effect": "Allow",
                          "Resource": {
                              "Fn::Sub": [
                                  "${arn}/*",
                                  {
                                      "arn": {
                                          "Ref": "CustomerS3BucketARN"
                                      }
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      }                      
                  ]
              },
              "Roles": [
                  {
                      "Ref": "InstanceRole"
                  }
              ]
          },
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                  "id": "a713fcc6-95c8-423f-a5b8-0020a81e5ce4"
              }
          }
      }
```